# How can I get ember data content from view?

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data, router

Model:

```
Blocks.NVD3Chart = Blocks.DSModel.extend({
    xAxis: DS.attr()
    ,series: DS.attr()
})

Blocks.NVD3Chart.FIXTURES = [
    {
        "id": "02c6486ac0a8017400348bcdb2029c63asdf"
        ,xAxis: [1,2]
        ,series: [
        {
            data: [10,20]
            ,name: "Employment"
        }
    ]
    }]
```

Route:

```
Blocks.LetsseeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('NVD3Chart')
    }
})
```

View:

```
Blocks.LetsseeView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'letssee',
    drawChart: function () {
        console.log(this.get("controller.content"))
        console.log(this.get("controller.model"))
    }.on("didInsertElement")
})
```

And I'm using the implicit controller declaration.
Here is the results of the log statement results that are called on didInsertElement. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCC2E.jpg)

Now, the problem comes down to retrieving the content from the controller. Inside the controller content's length is 0. The model does exist though and it does have a content. But the data within the first element of content is undefined. However, the _data property is defined, and contains the data I need. I don't want to utilize the _data values because it is a pristine copy ember data stores and I don't want to muck with it. What is the proper way of setting and retrieving the content from the route inside the controller/view? Is there something I am not doing properly?

Comment: Often times, the model is not fully resolved by the time the view is first created. So the promise might not have fulfilled before your 'didInsertElement` event. You should let the page finish loading, then lookup the view in the container and see if the data is complete after everything has settled. (Which seem unlikely given that the `_data` property is set, but we should start with the simplest things first.)

Comment: I tried lookup on the console for the controller and unfortunately, data is still undefined. Also, neither controller's model or content are promises. So theres no way to add a 'then' statement

Comment: The controller's `content` is the model. You shouldn't really be accessing that property directly though, it's only for the PromiseObject. And the model should definitely be a promise. Based on the code above, it should be a `DS.PromiseArray`.

Comment: I was expecting a DS.PromiseArray a well, but it's a DS.RecordArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround I did was using the content found within the model. And even though when logging object, data is undefined and all the data is stored inside _data for the model object, calling .get("data") on the object returns the expected results.

```
this.get("controller.model.content")[0].get("data")
```